# How can I create an add folder functionality to my React CMS application?

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system

[Click here to see a picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBx4u.png)

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure how to even approach this problem. I'm not even sure what to Google. I do, however, have a pretty good handle on React. Thanks!

Update: The folders will not be storing files, just hyperlinks.

Comment: Could you give more information, where do you want to create hyper links on the mobile device or on the server?

Comment: Sure. I would like the user to be able to organize said hyperlinks as a list inside different folders. They would be created after the user submits a file to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to model the problem space first. i.e. models for folders, and files. Each having properties (name, etc.) and associations (folders can have many files and subfolders).

To store the physical files you can use a third-party service like Amazon S3.

This would get you started at least.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt answer. I will update the question to include the following information. The folders will not be storing files, just hyperlinks.